# Redirect to Thank you page after submission

Tags: php, forms, contacts

```
<?php
/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
AND ALSO SMTP TO SEND THE EMAILS
*/

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'noreply@ccc.com.my';
$fromName = 'Contact Form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'di@cccc.com.my';
$sendToName = 'Contact Form';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// smtp credentials and server

$smtpHost = 'mbox1.awania.net';
$smtpUsername = 'ccccc.com';
$smtpPassword = 'cccccc!';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'location' => 'location',);

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage =  'Thank you for your interest in Rolex watches. Your message has been successfully sent. One of our representatives will be reviewing your request and will send you a response as soon as possible.';


// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
*  LET'S DO THE SENDING
*/

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (count($_POST) == 0) {
        throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
    }
    
    $emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";
    
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a nice day,<br>Regards,<br>Swee Cheong Sdn. Bhd.</p>";
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
    $mail->addReplyTo($from);
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $emailTextHtml;
    $mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version of the HTML email, very handy
    
     echo "<script> ga('send', 'event', 'Form', 'Submission'); </script>";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false ;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    // use
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
    $mail->Host = 'mbox1.awania.net';
    
    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;
    
    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = $smtpUsername;
    
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = $smtpPassword;
    
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
    
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage); header("Location: sweecheong.com.my/thankyou"); exit();
    
    
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

I've updated the codes above. Contact form is working except i can't seem to figure out where to put the re-direction link to thank you page after submission. I have tried a few suggestions online but does not seem to work. I am not familiar with PHP so hoping someone will be kind enough to help me out. Thanks

Comment: "_but doesn't seem to work_" is not very meaningful. No redirect at all? Wrong page? Blank page? Any errors/notices in your browser's DevTools/Network tab?

Comment: It only display an ok message but doesn't redirect to the thank you page

Comment: $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    header("Location: https://www.sweecheong.com.my/thankyou"); 
exit();

Comment: am not sure whether my codes are correct.

Comment: "_It only display an ok message_" There doesn't seem to be an "ok message" in the code you posted, where do you output that message?

Comment: I have updated the codes above. Hope is clearer now

Comment: That replaced code no longer redirects to a different page.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong copy. Have added it back.

Comment: @DianahLing please don't answer comments. Just [edit] the question and clarify for everyone directly in the body of your question. Comments are not part of the Q&A.